# Select statement hanging in oracle

Tags: oracle11g

I'm having an odd issue.
Consider following function:

```
create or replace 
function
getCursor()
return sys_refcursor authid current_user
as
q varchar2(32767);
cur sys_refcursor;
begin
    q := '...a long select statement with many tables of 5000 characters...';
    open cur for q;
    return cur;
    close cur;
end;
```

A. I call this function in SQL Developer at moment X, and this function returns a result after a second, which is normal for this select statement (as if it has been used in open code).
B. I call this function at moment Y (10 seconds after moment X), and the session hangs.
C. I kill this session `alter system kill session '58,27105'` and the function call from B stops.
D. I alter `q` variable by adding a new line at random place of `q` variable and re-compile the function thus not modifying the query but simply touching the string containing it.
E. I repeat point A, and it works. Then I repeat point B and it hangs again.

What can be the problem?

Comment: How are you calling the function, and how are you displaying the returned cursor? Does it retrieve all of the result set or just the first chunk of rows? Which version of SQL Developer are you using, and do you see the same thing if you repeat this through another client, preferably SQL\*Plus? My guess would be the cursor from the first call is still open and it causing a problem for the client, which may potentially be a bug in an old version, but hard to tell.

Answer (score 0):

Nothing wrong with the query itself, it's your logic in the function killing it.

Consider this oversimplified example:

```
  create or replace function f_test ( i in  number )
     return   number
  is
  begin
     dbms_output.put_line ( 'Checkpoint 1' );

     return 1;

     dbms_output.put_line ( 'Checkpoint 2' );

  end;
  /

  Function created.

  SQL> set serverout on
  SQL> select f_test (123 ) from dual;

  F_TEST(123)
  -----------
            1

  Checkpoint 1
  SQL>
```

Note how the text "Checkpoint 2" is never reached?
Look at your code .. it's never closing the cursor .. so next time it runs .. it's fighting with an left over cursor.

Move the return to the LAST LINE of the function ... after the close .. and try it again.

Comment: If you close the cursor inside the function, the caller won't be able to use it.

Comment: Oh, right, he's using ref cursor ... forgot that .. :)  It's probably still being left open .. is the caller closing the cursor when it's finished with it??

Comment: I believe it's closed implicitly when it goes out of scope for the caller, e.g. the SQL query or PL/SQL block ends. Safer for the caller to close explicitly anyway of course, if it's from PL/SQL. But still, two calls shouldn't interfere with each other, each function invocation gets a different ref cursor. My guess is still that a buggy client is handling it wrong, though can't quite figure out how it could - haven't found a way to reproduce the effect.